# Intellij search all files (ctrl + shift + f) doesn't find all matches? Settings issue?

Tags: intellij-idea

Using intellij search all files (<kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>) it seems to only find the first 100 matches.

Is there a setting I need to change for it to find all matches?

Comment: I am not sure  but you can use `open in find window` to see all the matches.

Comment: @soorapadman IMO you are right and should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quit sure there is a facility . 
But you can use `Open in find window` option to see all of your matches